# Javascript, How to get functions to run properly & in correct order

Tags: javascript, function, canvas, setinterval

I've been researching/experimenting most of this afternoon to get this basic meditation app to work, and am only asking this question after hours of finding solutions on my own.

The meditation app is supposed to have 3 columns that represent Inhale, Hold, and Exhale, in seconds. Every time that the column/time reaches it's set time that column pauses and the next column begins increasing in height and with the seconds counter below it. When all three columns reach completion, a Breath Cycles counter increases by 1, all the bars reset and the process continues until tab close. (The current times are 5(inhale):20(hold):15(exhale).

I had the bars all increasing evenly, but in the process of changing things to work in order, the bars stopped moving altogether. I'm only including all the code I have right now because I have no idea what's important here. Thanks again for any ideas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


// Columns x1 == xPos, x2 == width, y1 == yPos ,y2 == height
x1a = 10, x2a = 50, y1a = 250, y2a = -10;
x1b = 50, x2b = 50, y1b = 250, y2b = -10;
x1c = 100, x2c = 50, y1c = 250, y2c = -10;

inhaleTime = 5;
holdTime = 20;
exhaleTime = 10;

breathCounter = 0;

timerA = 1;
timerB = 1;
timerC = 1;


function render() {


  //Draw background      
  ctx.fillStyle = "#49faff";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 500);


  //Draw column A
  ctx.fillStyle = "#045f84";
  ctx.fillRect(x1a, y1a, x2a, y2a);


  //Draw column B
  ctx.fillStyle = "#14fe14";
  ctx.fillRect(x1b, y1b, x2b, y2b);

  //Draw column C
  ctx.fillStyle = "#d600f0";
  ctx.fillRect(x1c, y1c, x2c, y2c);


  //Write seconds counter under column A
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.font = "48px serif";
  ctx.strokeText(timerA, 10, 300);


  //Write seconds counter under column B
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.font = "48px serif";
  ctx.strokeText(timerB, 50, 300);


  //Write seconds counter under column C
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.font = "48px serif";
  ctx.strokeText(timerC, 100, 300);


  //Write breath cycles counter above columns 
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.font = "48px serif";
  ctx.strokeText(("Breath Cycles: " + breathCounter), 10, 100);


}


// Increase column A height by 1 unit & increase seconds counter by 1
function renderA() {
  x1a += 0;
  x2a += 0;
  y1a += 0;
  y2a += -100;

  timerA += 1;
}

// Increase column B height by 1 unit & increase seconds counter by 1
function renderB() {

  x1b += 0;
  x2b += 0;
  y1b += 0;
  y2b += -100;

  timerB += 1;
}


// Increase column C height by 1 unit & increase seconds counter by 1
function renderC() {
  x1c += 0;
  x2c += 0;
  y1c += 0;
  y2c += -100;

  timerC += 1;

}


//Reset column heights after each breath cycle & add 1 to Breath Cycles counter
function renderReset() {
  x1a = 10, x2a = 50, y1a = 250, y2a = -10;
  x1b = 50, x2b = 50, y1b = 250, y2b = -10;
  x1c = 100, x2c = 50, y1c = 250, y2c = -10;

  breathCounter += 1;

}




function updateRender() {

  renderA();
  renderB();
  renderC();



  //  setInterval(renderA, 1000);
  // setInterval(renderB, 1000);
  //  setInterval(renderC, 1000);

}


/*
    if (timerA > inhaleTime){
        timerA = 1;
        x1a = 10, x2a = 50, y1a = 250, y2a = -10; 
        x1b = 50, x2b = 50, y1b = 250, y2b = -10; 
        x1c = 100, x2c = 50, y1c = 250, y2c = -10; 
    }   


     if (timerA > inhaleTime && timerB > holdTime){
        timerA = 1;
        x1a = 10, x2a = 50, y1a = 250, y2a = -10; 
        x1b = 50, x2b = 50, y1b = 250, y2b = -10; 
        x1c = 100, x2c = 50, y1c = 250, y2c = -10; 
    }


     if (timerA > inhaleTime && timerB > holdTime && timerC > exhaleTime){
        

        timerA = 1;
        x1a = 10, x2a = 50, y1a = 250, y2a = -10; 
        x1b = 50, x2b = 50, y1b = 250, y2b = -10; 
        x1c = 100, x2c = 50, y1c = 250, y2c = -10; 
    }          
    
}
          
function inhaleBreath(){
    //increase barA                         x1a += 0; x2a += 0; y1a += 0; y2a += -10; 

    //increase timerA                        timerA += 1;
    //check if timer > inhaleTime


}


function holdBreath(){
    //increase barB                        x1b += 0; x2b += 0; y1b += 0; y2b += -10; 
    //increase timerB                      timerB += 1;
    //check if timer > holdTime
}


function exhaleBreath(){
    //increase barC                        x1c += 0; x2c += 0; y1c += 0; y2c += -10; 
    //increase timerC                      timerC += 1;
    //check if timer > exhaleTime
}

*/


render();
renderA();
//
//Insert functions to continually increment column heights, seconds counter, and breath counter 
//
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My first thought on seeing your code is that you need to refactor all those variables: use arrays of objects, specifically an array with three elements each of which is an object holding the state of a column. That would neaten the code *and* make it easier to have a function that just animates whichever column is the "current" one.

Comment: nnnnnn, thank you very much, I will look into that

Cache Staheli, I did go for as "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" as possible while still maintaining as much clarity as possible of what I was going for. All those comments were added and some re-arranging/deleting of code done entirely for the sake of posting on here.

Comment: You need to call `updateRender` at regular intervals. Add this to the end of that function `requestAnimationFrame(updateRender)`  RAF at the end of each frame this will call the update again at regular intervals. Next  RAF will call the function with the time so add `updateRender(frameTime)` you now have the time in 1/1000th sec. if you want something to happen in 20 second, set a variable for that time `nextEvent = frameTime + 20 * 1000` Then `if(frameTime > nextEvent) {` call what is needed and set up the next

Comment: thanks for the RAF explanation, read over the w3c's and this explained the concept in a refreshingly simple and concise manner

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll bite ...

Here's a version of your breathing bars that use a single `requestAnimationFrame` loop rather than multiple timers.

The key is to calculate the elapsed time within the current breathing cycle.

Given:

```
// milliseconds for each part of the breathing cycle
var maxInhale=5000;
var maxHold=20000;
var maxExhale=15000;
```

- If the elapsed time is < 5 seconds,

  ```
  // where each pct is between 0.00 & 1.00 (==0% to 100%)
  pctInhale = elapsed / maxCycleTime
  pctHold = 0;
  pctExhale = 0;
  ```
- If the elapsed time is < (5+20) 25 seconds,

  ```
  pctInhale=1;
  pctHold=(elapsed-maxInhale)/maxHold;
  pctExhale = 0;
  ```
- If the elapsed time is < (5+20+15) 40 seconds,

  ```
  pctInhale=1;
  pctHold=1;
  pctExhale=(elapsed-maxInhale-maxHold)/maxExhale
  ```

**Example code and a Demo:**

## Please view demo in full screen mode :-)

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var maxInhale=5000;
var maxHold=20000;
var maxExhale=15000;
var maxCycle=maxInhale+maxHold+maxExhale;
var cycleStartTime=0;
var xa=50;
var xb=150;
var xc=250;
var width=75;
var maxHeight=300;
var maxY=ch-100;

ctx.font='36px verdana';
ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function draw(pctInhale,pctHold,pctExhale){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#49faff";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);     
    //Draw column A
    ctx.fillStyle = "#045f84";
    ctx.fillRect(xa,maxY,width,-maxHeight*pctInhale);
    //Draw column B
    ctx.fillStyle = "#14fe14";
    ctx.fillRect(xb,maxY,width,-maxHeight*pctHold);
    //Draw column C
    ctx.fillStyle = "#d600f0";
    ctx.fillRect(xc,maxY,width,-maxHeight*pctExhale);

    ctx.fillStyle='red';
    ctx.fillText(parseInt(maxInhale*pctInhale/1000)+'s',xa+width/2,maxY-48);
    ctx.fillText(parseInt(maxHold*pctHold/1000)+'s',xb+width/2,maxY-48);
    ctx.fillText(parseInt(maxExhale*pctExhale/1000)+'s',xc+width/2,maxY-48);
}

function animate(time){
    var elapsed=time-cycleStartTime;
    // cycle done? start over.
    if(elapsed>maxCycle){
        cycleStartTime=time;
        elapsed=0;
    }
    // calc each bars percentage based on elapsed time
    var pctInhale=0;
    var pctHold=0;
    var pctExhale=0;    
    if(elapsed<maxInhale){
        pctInhale=elapsed/maxInhale;
    }else if(elapsed<maxInhale+maxHold){
        pctInhale=1;
        pctHold=(elapsed-maxInhale)/maxHold;
    }else if(elapsed<maxInhale+maxHold+maxExhale){
        pctInhale=1;
        pctHold=1;
        pctExhale=(elapsed-maxInhale-maxHold)/maxExhale
    }
    // draw the bars
    draw(pctInhale,pctHold,pctExhale);
    // request another animation loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=700 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, that is awesome. I was making progress with the object refactoring, but I'm just gonna add a breath cycles counter that adds 1 every 35 seconds until I figure out exactly what's going on in this code. Thank you so so much, and I'm actually pretty amazed at how many good responses I got in such a short amount of time. Thumbs up to everyone (hopefully I'll soon be skilled enough to earn some points answering questions so the thumbs up actually show). Keep up the great work everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stick with your existing code as much as possible and added what I needed to add.  At the bottom of your code I added the following:

```
var whichCounter = 'A';

function newUpdate() {
  //console.log('newUpdate, A=' + timerA + ', B=' + timerB + ', C=' + timerC);

  render();
  switch (whichCounter) {
    case 'A':
      if (timerA < inhaleTime) {
        renderA();
      } else {
        timerB = 1;
        whichCounter = 'B';
      }
      break;
    case 'B':
      if (timerB < holdTime) {
        renderB();
      } else {
        timerC = 1;
        whichCounter = 'C';
      }
      break;
    case 'C':
      if (timerC < exhaleTime) {
        renderC();
      } else {
        whichCounter = 'Q';
      }
      break;
    case 'Q':
      timerA = 1;
      timerB = 1;
      timerC = 1;
      renderReset();
      whichCounter = 'A';
      render();
      break;
  }
}
setInterval(newUpdate, 1000);
```

You can see it in action in [this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20co2hjj/25/).